# What is the global model?

Tags: aic, overdispersion

I'm trying to calculate c-hat, the overdispersion parameter for a QAIC model set.  According to Burnham and Anderson, you're supposed to calculate c-hat on the global model.  Is the global model the model from the a priori set that has the most parameters, or is it a separate model not in the candidate set that includes a combination of all parameters used in the candidate set?

For example, with this candidate set of models:

```
1 grass+trees
2 grass*trees
3 grass*trees^2
4 shrubs
5 river
```

Is the global model simply model #3, or is i: grass*trees^2+shrubs+river ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: both.

Longer answer: Ideally, your global model would consist of all variables thought to be useful to your particular research question. It would represent the most complex model whose subsets would contain all the terms being considered by the other models within your candidate set. Of course, such a global model might be potentially huge, especially if including all possible interaction terms.

Given the above, I would say that your global model appears to be:

6 grass*trees^2+shrubs+river

Burnham and Andersen (2002) discuss the global model in more detail and why you might want to include it in your analysis. It appears to be included as a means of testing the overall fit, with the notion that if the global model doesn't fit the data well, then it's likely that subsets of that global model, which would exist in your candidate set, won't either. Specifically, look at section 1.3.6, p.26 of B&A's (2002) book for more information.

HTH